# JBoss AS 7 and http threads - is there only one thread processing the requests by clients?

Tags: java, jboss7.x, threadpool

I have a java servlet where I am printing out the name of the current thread. It is always the same thread that is processing my requests, no matter of how many times I press the refresh button on my browser. The thread is always `http--127.0.0.1-8080-1`. **Does that mean that there is only one thread in the pool that is handling all requests?**

What I can remember when I went a course on Java EE is that there were different threads in the pool processing the requests when I pressed the refresh button many times. The output could be:

```
http--127.0.0.1-8080-1
http--127.0.0.1-8080-3
http--127.0.0.1-8080-2
http--127.0.0.1-8080-5
```

Now it is always `http--127.0.0.1-8080-1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've checked with JBoss 4.2.3, JBoss 6.0.0, and JBoss 7.1.1: Sometimes the thread changes, sometimes not.

When I accessed the same web app from different browser instances, in the first browser it did not change, in the other one it did change.

In the JBoss 6.0.0 admin console, located in Resources / JBoss Web / Connectors / `http://127.0.0:8080`, you can see the number of active threads, and the total thread count. In my case, active = 2 and count = 7. I have not found this information in JBoss 7.1.1 admin console. But using two browser instances showed that at least two different threads are used.

So it's probably not deterministic which thread is being selected from the pool, and one or two browser sessions just do not create enough traffic.

Comment: Thank you! I tried to access the web app from another browser and then another thread was used. I have set the `max-connections` attribute in standalone.xml to 100, so I guess that 100 different threads can be created if 100 clients called the web app simultaneously. I will check further with VisualVM.